# how can I specify controller and method in a link using haml with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am new in ralis, and I am trying to create a link in what calls an specific method of a specific controller, in this case car and method add_to_cart sending a parameters, unfortunately I dont know how to do it

For example, I want something this, but even if I scape characters

```
= link_to "Add to cart", {:controller => "car", :action => "add_to_cart", :car => car.id }
```

If I paste it just like that I get an error saying **No route matches** , any way to make it? or maybe in the old format (I dont understand it) I guess should be something like

```
=link_to "car", add_to_cart_car_path(@car.id), class: "btn"
```

Also shows me an error,

Any idea of this?

Comment: Are you calling this the way `add_to_cart_car` is specified in the routes file? Check `rake routes` for the signature of this route. Also note you should not call `id` on things passed in to the routing system, that's only for direct SQL calls. The router will handle the conversion if necessary, and models can define their own `to_param` that behaves differently from the default.

Comment: you are right, that route it is not defined (some routes are not defined on my routes.rb file, how can I add them? )

Comment: add it like any other rails route

Comment: Please list your current routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a route setup for the resource called `car`:

```
resources :cars
```

You can add a member action by changing it to:

```
resources :cars do
  get :add_to_cart, :on => :member
end
```

You can now write:

```
= link_to "Add to Cart", add_to_cart_car_path(@car), class: 'btn'
```

Comment: what does the :on => :member mean?

Comment: It means that this route should be on a specific resource (a member - in this case a specific car), rather than on the collection of cars

Comment: It also has the effect of adding `:id` to the path, where that ID refers to a particular *member*.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the route to routes.rb:

```
match 'add_to_cart' => 'cars#add_to_cart'
```

Remember to restart your rails server for the new route to be recognized.